# ContextMenu WPF get access from behind code

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a ContextMenu for a ListView.

in a normal situation ListView's ContextMenu has the following Items:

- New Folder
- (*Separator*)
- Paste (if `copiedCollection!=null`)
- (*Separator*)
- Properties

and I have a main Address `ExploreAddress` which hold the currentAddress,
When this Address = "My Computer", then I'd want to change the contextMenu Items to just:

- Properties

(because you can't Paste or make a new folder on "My Computer Address")

I'm thinking of creating an event handler to the class `ExploreAddress` so whenever the address changed, it checks `if (Address =="My Computer")` then it changes the `contextMenu`'s Items.

so my first question is How to **Create/Change** the ContextMenu's Items from the code?

the second question is How would I change `IsEnabled Value` of the ContextMenuItem **Paste** when `copiedCollection !=null`

Comment: have you tried that on ContextMenuOpening event?